# What is the biggest haul when it comes to Courier/Delivery Missions?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I am trying to [outfit](https://coriolis.edcd.io/outfit/python?code=A0pktiFflidpssf57l7l7l0s0s040403044f050504375d0202C5.Iw18eQ%3D%3D.EwBj4hGafTTMIA%3D%3D.&bn=CourierMissions) a Python for Courier, Salvage and Delivery Missions.

While the Python can take over 200T, it leaves you pretty weak against interdictions by NPC. PVP is not a consideration here.

I would like to be prepared for anything, so I am wondering, what is the biggest known haul when it comes to those kind of missions?

ps.: Engineering is not available to me.

Comment: @dpeif The most cargo one mission would ask to transport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *seems* to be capped somewhere below 200 units for a single mission, though I can't find a recent, definitive source.
The requested cargo quantities do seem tied (loosely) to the trade rank of the mission / pilot, i.e. **higher rank tends to produce higher quantity requests**, but amounts vary substantially depending on the mission.

There don't seem to be any authoritative listings of specific missions scenarios, e.g. actual cargo amounts and required ranks. The best I could do was crawl screenshots until I found [a forum post from **2015**](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php/200323-Long-Distance-Trading-and-Smuggling-Missions-in-1-5) that includes some actual screenshots from in-game.

[image: trade-1]
[image: trade-2]
[image: trade-3]

**Keep in mind this information is dated**, but it shows several different ranked missions, from Peddler to Elite. The quantity of the cargo does not seem tied directly to the rank of the mission (Merchant has a few higher quantity missions than the Elites), but the higher ranks do seem to have the biggest quantities.

The highest listed in this forum post is **138 units for a Merchant-rank mission**, but Cmdr Freiheit has added in comments that he has seen **upwards of 160 units** for an Elite mission. These are the highest quantities I can find out-of-game, and my rank is only Broker at the moment, so I am unable to test in-game.

Comment: I think I've seen missions asking for up to 192 tons to be delivered, but I'm Elite in Trade...  Definitely done some missions that needed slightly over 150 tons delivered (160).

Comment: @CmdrFreiheit gotcha, you are an authoritative source IMHO so i will edit accordingly

Comment: I suggest putting "it depends on trade rank" in bold at the top.